# XAML error MC3074 occurring only on pipeline

Tags: c#, xaml, azure-devops, pipeline

I've been searching for any existing information on this problem but so far i've turned up nothing. I moved a XAML file from an existing project within the C# solution to a new project i added, and after updating namespaces, the solution compiles locally for me and everyone else who's looked at my changes.

However, when i tried to merge my work, the ADO pipeline succeeds at compilation but fails at UWP Appx packaging with the message "##[error]IsenCommonLib\Views\DeviceControl.xaml(97,14): Error MC3074: The tag 'GenericLoader' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:HP.Omen.OmenControls.Views;assembly=OmenControls'. Line 97 Position 14.". The XAML control GenericLoader definitely *does* exist in this namespace, and it's used about a dozen other times throughout the codebase with no issues. The only changes made to the XAML file i moved were updating namespaces, and so far neither me nor anyone else who's pulled my branch have been able to find anything wrong. I'm completely stumped at this point.

Possibly relevant, i added the new project by copy-pasting an existing project and editing it in order to get all the boilerplate configuration for free instead of having to manually reconfigure everything. I know that's a really good way to miss something and have stuff break, but i've checked everything i've found in threads relating to error MC2074 and i haven't found anything that's not how it should be.

Answer (score 0):

A coworker found the problem, the new project was set to build in a configuration used only by the pipeline which prevented the problem from showing up locally for anyone. Removing the project from building in said config solved the issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).